# Unlimited User Session time on Worklight Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on a mobile application project based on IBM worklight. I am using Worklight Single step form based authentication for log in module to validate user and create user session on server. 
Now what is need is to keep user session active until user log out from the app regardless application run in background or foreground.

I read worklight documentation for server tuning, but that stated user session can be keep active by setting heart beat interval and server session timeout. That is working fine when app run in foreground but when app goes to background heart beat stops and user session get invalidated after specified server session time out . **So is there any way to make server session timeout unlimited**.Any help will be appreciated.

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0 and WebSpere Application server V8.5 and building app for iPad/iphone devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: [Optimization and tuning of Worklight Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_optimizing_and_tuning_of_ibm_wl_server.html), you should be able to modify the serverSessionTimeout property to get closer to the behavior you want.

Make sure that you really want to do it, the Worklight team has a nice explanation on why the heartBeat stops sending when the app is in the background:

"For example, suppose every minute 1,000 users start a session against the server. Even if they exit the application after 3 minutes, their sessions remain active on the server for 10 minutes, leaving 10 x 1,000 = 10,000 active sessions."

Comment: Orlando Rincón thanks for your concern, can you tell me what will be the best value to set for heartBeat and ServerSessionTimeout to achieve this? I really want to do it like facebook, gmail etc.

Comment: Well, I think that's up to you. The maximum serverSessionTimeout value you can set is 35791394 (this is a "minutes" value), which would be equivalent to 68+ years. Of course this is huge and your server would run out of resources very quick handling all those inactive sessions. If you want to go this way I'd recommend a one week value (604800). For heartbeat it just needs to be lower than serverSessionTimeout (just a reminder that heartbeat is expressed in seconds).

Comment: However, I think a better option would be to listen to [setOnAppEnteringForeground event](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_app_backgroundhandler_setOnAppEnteringForeground.html?resultof=%22%66%6f%72%65%67%72%6f%75%6e%64%22%20) and use [JSONStore](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_08_JSONStore_-_The_client_side_JSON_based_database_overview.pdf) to save login credentials (if possible) to force a re-login into the application every time it's brought to top.

Comment: Orlando Rincón thanks i will try to implement it. Thanks again :)